# How to programmatically add display to running Rviz instance?

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a package that is meant to be run after a 3rd-party package starts Rviz. My package simply provides a new display type, and some topics for that display type to subscribe to.

Currently, I have to launch the 3rd-party package, then launch my package, then manually add and configure the display type to Rviz. It would be nice if in the launch file for my package I could automatically add and configure the display.

Is this at all possible? I don't think Rviz exposes any services for this, or allows you to 'force' it to reload a custom config file, so I don't know how this would be possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76675/how-to-programmatically-add-display-to-running-rviz-instance?/) by [danep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2877/danep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2877/danep/) on 2013-09-05**:
I thought about that, but it was too ugly to seriously consider :)

I guess I'll just resort to hacking the other package's config file, and maintaining a vendor branch. It would be nice if there were a Better Way in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only (hacky) way I see would be to add a 'rosnode kill' on the rviz instance launched by the 3rd party package and an rviz instance with a different config to your own launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0